# Difference in calling the activity

Tags: android, android-activity

What is the difference when I call an activity from :

1. Same package
2. Different Package
3. Different Android Applications ?

The 1st two options worked good for me.But due to some reasons, I am trying to call Activities from different android applications, which mostly causes problem in my HTTP connection.

If same thing I implement via 1st or 2nd option, everything works fine.So, I know that there is some difference in option 3.But I don't know what it is.

The calling method is same :

```
intent = new Intent(main.this, fullPackageName.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

**Is there any logical difference? When we try to call an activity from a different android application rather that same project??**

Comment: Why do you have to call directly an activity from another app ? Can't you use intent-filter and actions like it is for sharing, taking picture, selecting file, etc) ?

Comment: @StephaneMathis Basically I am working on an API which gives its modules as different applications.So I am using/calling them by making  them libraries.

Comment: And what exactly isn't working ? Internet connection ? Did you specify the required permission in the manifest of the libraries ?

Comment: @StephaneMathis yes, all the permission are included.It is creating an HTTP login .Which hangs only calling activity via another app.I was wondering what is the difference?Are any  FLAGS automatically set?

Comment: Then I don't know. I've used the same thing in the past without problem.

Answer (score -2):

I think you problem is solved by Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL).

Comment: Is not there any easy way around?